# Is it possible to upload an Android app (with split APKs) and an iOS app with same package IDs to Fabric Beta?

Tags: google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I'm developing a React Native application. We are using [Fabric](http://fabric.io/) for beta testing. Is it possible to upload

- Android app with split APKs ("armeabi-v7a" and "x86")
- iOS app

with the same package ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! Yes this is possible, however you will need to create blank apps in AS and Xcode to get the initial skeleton setup in Fabric. Then you will be able to distribute your React Native app for both platforms.

Comment: Thanks, I just got both projects up and running. One question though, I am still not sure if I can upload the split APK's and the correct one will be 
automatically downloaded to the user device